# How do I install Ubuntu permanently on a thumb drive as if it were a hard disk?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I've heard about "live sticks" and even created one, however, all they apparently offer is a "demo" and an install program. Additionally, either the permanence thing doesn't work or it's because my computer gets stuck on the shutdown process.

What I want instead would be to write Ubuntu *onto the disk like onto a hard drive*.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried booting from CD / Live USB stick and installing to another USB stick?... I don't see why it _wouldn't_ work... Performance will probably be abysmal though.

Comment: It is possible and the process is the same, you just select a different drive. Of course, the USB stick where you want it installed cannot be the same you're booting from the live session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually *very* simple.  You just need two USB thumbdrives.  Create a Live USB on one thumbdrive, run the install and point the installation to the second thumbdrive.  Just be sure you are writing to the correct location, as to not overwrite something else.

I am actively running Linux off a 2GB thumbdrive for a file server, so I could dedicate all the SATA connections to hard drives.